# Div not centering in IE or Firefox, Works correctly in Safari and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, html, center

So my homepage to my site will not center correctly in firefox or IE. It appears to be working fine in chrome and safari. My site can be found at http://koltondallas.com/ I apologize in advance because im sure it's something easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bad type attribute:

This:
`<link href="style.css" type="text/ccss" rel="stylesheet"></link>`

Should be:
`<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>`